# MySQL SELECT JOIN ON 3 tables "continue" query also if 1 join returns nothing

Tags: mysql

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
SELECT 

    t1.id t1_id, t1.title t1_title, t1.subtitle t1_subtitle, t1.content t1_content, 
    t2.title t2_title, t2.newfilename t2_newfilename, 
    t3.picture t3_picture 

FROM webcms_cms_content t1 

INNER JOIN webcms_cms_downloads t2 
    ON t1.id = t2.content_id 

INNER JOIN webcms_mod_galleries_pictures t3 
    ON t1.gallery_id = t3.gallery_id 

WHERE t1.structure_id =3 
AND t1.status=1 
AND t1.flag=1 
ORDER BY t1.newsdatum DESC, t3.rang ASC
```

Now the problem is that sometimes one of the joins don't return anything but the other one would. So I want always to get the data also if one join returns nothing.

To be more detailed:

```
    INNER JOIN webcms_cms_downloads t2 
    ON t1.id = t2.content_id
```

it could be that there are no downloads, but the next join

```
    INNER JOIN webcms_mod_galleries_pictures t3 
    ON t1.gallery_id = t3.gallery_id
```

would return something so I would like to get that part. Now it "brakes" and doesnt returns anything if the first join is empty.

Is this possible in just one query? How should I do it?

Thanks for all suggestions and help!

Comment: Change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers, this should give you a hint of what join to use.

[image: Sql Joins]

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN`s  instead of `INNER JOIN`s  for exactly that.